# Selenium/java PhantomJs driver.get(loginURL) gets login url on first run. On Second run it driver.get(loginURL) to home page

Tags: selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

Selenium/java PhantomJs:

On First run,  `driver.get(loginURL)`, gets login url.

On the Second run, `driver.get(loginURL)`, goes to the home page, instead of the login page. And of course it doesn't find elements of the login page.

(A scenario execution might fail and log out my not be performed at the end)

Any help? Any ideas why this is happening?

Thanks

Code Part and exception:

```
...
WebDriver driver;
PhantomJSDriverService phantomService = PhantomJSDriverService.createDefaultService();
System.setProperty("phantomjs.binary.path", "browserDrivers/phantomjs.exe");
driver = new PhantomJSDriver();

driver.get("https://xxxxxx/yy/");
System.out.println("Url :" + driver.getCurrentUrl());  
WebElement loginField = driver.findElement(By.id("txt-username"));
WebElement passwdField = driver.findElement(By.id("txt-password"));
...
```

Reults of console printout:

1st Run: Url :https://xxxxxx/yy/login (correct and also finds next WebElements), fails in next steps

2st Run: Url :https://xxxxxx/yy/home (incorrect should be login page again https://xxxxxx/yy/login)

> Exception thrown:  org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException:
>   {"errorMessage":"Unable to find element with id 'txt-username'"

Comment: Qunestion is not clear. Can you elaborate more.

Answer (score 0):

For a proper cleanup (logout after failure in your case) you can implement a teardown method which is executed *after each test in your test class*, e.g. like this (using Junit4):

```
@org.junit.After
public void tearDown() {
    //your code for performing logout
    //....

    //Close the current window, quitting the browser 
    //if it's the last window currently open.
    if (driver != null) {
        driver.close();
    }
}
```